# Cron job execution time

Tags: cron, last-modified

I added a job for backup to my cron jobs, using `crontab -e`:

```
0 0 * * * tar -czf /somewhere/backup.tar.gz --exclude='sth/backup' --directory='/var/www' sth
```

But when I check the created file, with `stat`, it shows this:

```
Access: 2015-08-26 11:55:48.000667280 +0430
Modify: 2015-09-03 08:30:07.946818661 +0430
Change: 2015-09-03 08:30:07.946818661 +0430
```

As you see, the modification time of the file is 08:30. But in the crontab, I have set this to execute on 00:00 (12 at midnight).

Why is this happening?

Comment: Perhaps it took 8.5 hours to complete?

Comment: Oh, no! It takes about 4 or 5 seconds only.

Comment: What is the output of `crontab -u USER -l`

Comment: A lot of comments, followed by my commands, including the one that is in the question.

Comment: Is the correct timezone set? Also please check your hardware clock.

Comment: I'd guess that this is because of time zone confusion. The output from stat suggests that your shell is operating in UTC+0430 (Afghanistan?). Sounds like cron is running in a different time zone. Looking at /var/log/cron might clarify this.

Comment: @PaulHaldane, both of the commands are running on same server, so what do you mean exactly? This is not afghanistan, it's Iran, And I could not find /var/log/cron. I'm on a debian.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/54364 for possible solutions.  Set a cron job to run `date>/sonewhere/test.txt` at midnight and see what time zone is in the output file.

Comment: @cxw I will try that and will let you know

Comment: @cxw I tried that and this is the answer: `Fri Sep  4 08:30:01 IRDT 2015`

Comment: Last question (I hope)- what is `ls -l /etc/localtime`?  Your cron appears to be running in `America/New_York` or some other UTC-4 time zone, and I'm wondering where that setting is coming from. (Note: once we sort this out, I'm going to post an answer and delete my comments :) )

Comment: No, I believe my local time is right. But one possibility came to my mind today. The server is up about 102 days. Maybe sometime I've changed my timezone, and did not restart cron. So I restarted and waiting to see what happens.

Comment: What news after the restart?

Comment: I forgot to check that! Everything is OK now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was originating from that I had changed the server's timezone a long time ago, but because I did not restart my server for several months, the changes did not apply to the `cron` service.

**The main point is** you have to restart the `cron` service after changing the timezone in order to take effect.